# GUIs in java: why am I instantiating an object to display a GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

As you may be able to tell, this program simply displays a GUI with "My name is Bob" inside a JFrame. I'm relatively new to programming, and I still can't figure out why the "**NameGUI greeting = new NameGUI();**" code is needed within the runGUI method. It appears to me that it is simply instantiating an object that is never used. However, when I take that code fragment out, the GUI does not display. What am I missing?

```
    public NameGUI() { 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Name"); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel nameSpace = new JPanel(); 
        JLabel name = new JLabel("My name is Bob"); 
        nameSpace.add(name); 
        frame.setContentPane(nameSpace);
        frame.pack(); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public static void runGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        NameGUI greeting = new NameGUI(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
            runGUI();
            }       
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see the opening round bracket for  ` }); `

Comment: `why am I instantiating an object to display a GUI?` - not sure why you are doing that. There is no need to structure your code like that. You could just move all that code into the runGui() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It appears to me that it is simply instantiating an object that is never used.

You're sort of right. What this line `NameGUI greeting = new NameGUI();` does is to *create a variable that is never used*, the variable `greeting`. Probably cleaner would be to do:

```
public static void runGUI() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    new NameGUI(); 
}
```

And that's it. But understand that in both situations a NameGUI object is created, and it **is** used -- it's constructor creates the JFrame and displays it.